# array initialization for one of the elements in the structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have initialized the array for one of the element in the structure, there were some errors in printing the output, please point the errors and guide in solving it . Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct person
{
int row[3];
int age;
}PERSON;

int main()
{
 int i;
 PERSON p;
 PERSON *pptr=&p;
 pptr->row[3] = {4,5,6};

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  printf (" %d\n", pptr->row[i]);

 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting ?

Comment: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Answer (score 1):

Array objects in C language are not assignable. You cannot set the values in the entire array by using assignment. So, to do what you are trying to do using assignment syntax is impossible.

You had a chance to initialize your array at the point of declaration, i.e. when you defined object `p`

```
PERSON p = { { 4, 5, 6 }  };
```

but you did not use that chance. After that it is too late to do it using pure core language features.

To set the values in the entire array after the point of declaration you can use a library function, like `memcpy`, in combination with a compound literal

```
memcpy(pptr->row, (int []) {4, 5, 6}, sizeof pptr->row);
```

Comment: `memcpy(pptr->row, (int []) {4, 5, 6}, sizeof *pptr->row);` seems to be yielding wrong result: http://liveworkspace.org/code/NTUwNT$7 . BTW, `PERSON p = { { 4, 5, 6 }  };` gives a warning about missing initializer - though it seems weird to me since the missing one should be initialized to 0 by C standard

Comment: @icepack: I made a typo. It should be `sizeof pptr->row`. I fixed the answer. The missing field is indeed initialized to `0`, as required by the language. GCC just decided to issue one of those annoying warnings for it. It is one of those cases when it is indeed "just a warning".

Comment: Hmm, still something I don't understand. Your typo has affected the size being copied but the result showed the wrong value was the second one, both first and third values seem correct

Comment: @icepack: I'm not sure I follow. When I look at your liveworkspace link, I see that only the first value is correct, while the second and third one are wrong (which is perfectly explainable by the typo). Once the typo is fixed, all three values become correct. Where did you see both first and third values as correct with the second one being wrong?

Comment: Sorry, looked again at the results. I must have been hallucinating the previous time...

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign values to array like this: `pptr->row[3] = {4,5,6};`. Such syntax is valid only at initialization. You need to set each value manually or initialize your array with the values you want, something like this: `PERSON p = {{4,5,6}, 0};`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have done `PERSON p;`. object `p` is created containing `indeterminate values`.
It means all the data members are already initialized with garbage since it's on stack.

So, `pptr->row[3] = {4,5,6};` is not the initialization of the array an not allowed in this case. The `for` loop method is the best in this case.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   scanf("%d",&(pptr->row[i]));  // prenthrsis is for human readability
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct person
{
int row[3];
int age;
}PERSON;

int main()
{
 int i;
 PERSON p;
 PERSON *pptr=&p;
 pptr->row[0] = 4;
 pptr->row[1] = 5;
 pptr->row[2] = 6;

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  printf (" %d\n", pptr->row[i]);

 }
return 0;
}
```

You can't initialize array like this `pptr->row[3] = {4,5,6};`, You can use the above method or use `for` loop to initialize array..